# About convex functions

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Is there a non negative, convex, and decreasing function $g$ on $[0,\infty)$, with $g(0)=1$, such that $g(s+t)< g(t)g(s)$ for $s,t \in (0,\infty)$?

Comment: I guess you mean "for all $s,t>0$", since otherwise taking $s=t=0$ would yield $1<1$. Then $g(t)=1+t$ would work.

Comment: yes, you are right.

Comment: I added the word decreasing in the question. Is there such a function?

Comment: Maybe $g(t) =2^{1-t}-1$

Comment: Thanks. Now comes the real challenge. Our function must be non negative. Is there such a function?

Comment: $e^{-t^2-2t}$ should work, unless you keep adding more conditions. Btw I think a better place to ask this question would be mathstackexchange